# How to stripe a text in span using bootstrap class

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I have some `<span>`'s

```html
<span>SOME TEXT HERE</span>
<span> MORE TEXT</span>
<span class="the-bootstrap-class-to-stripe-text">ANOTHER TEXT BUT STRIPED</span>
```

I did not find how to stripe a text in bootstrap.

I solved it using

```html
<span><s>ANOTHER TEXT BUT STRIPED</s></span>
```

but is there another way? Does that bootstrap class exist?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're looking for the following class:

```
text-decoration-line-through
```

---

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<span class='text-decoration-line-through'>bootstap</span>
```

---

In the [*Text decoration* family](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/utilities/text/#text-decoration), there are also:

- `text-decoration-underline`
- `text-decoration-none`

Answer (score 0):

Yes,.text-decoration-line-through https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/utilities/text/#text-decoration

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<span class='text-decoration-line-through'>same answer</span>
```

Comment: Even tho I've already provided the same answer, you could improve your answer by copying OP's snippet, and showing how the `text-decoration-line-through` works! That way OP does not have to check the link for an example. Consider reading about [link only answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259/844268) and [ask].

Comment: I answered at the same time and did not notice how you already answered, sorry!